# generic link_to helper for new nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a generic view for tasks, since many models can have tasks polymorphically. So in various other views I render this generic partial, and I pass the owning model as "taskable". The problem is I am having trouble rendering the new action in this view. I want to render a view like:

```
new_lead_task_path
new_client_task_path
```

I have tried the following:

```
link_to [:new, taskable, Task.new]
```

but it gives the error:

```
undefined method `new_lead_tasks_path'
```

Notice how it looks for "tasks" and not "task". It should have been new_lead_task_path.

What might I be doing wrong?

The route looks like this:

```
new_lead_task GET      /leads/:lead_id/tasks/new(.:format)                            tasks#new
```

Comment: Can you post your routes? $ rake routes

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka the route I am trying to generate is this one: new_lead_task_path

Comment: it's probably something like: 

get 'tasks/:task_id/leads/new' => 'leads#new', as: 'new_lead_taks'

Comment: You can make it more elegant if you show how your routes file look like

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka the route has this pattern: /leads/:lead_id/tasks/new(.:format) Task belongs_to Lead polymorphically as taskable.

Comment: Yeah, polymorphic associations are a little tricky to get those dynamic links to work. You should probably check polymorphic_path

Comment: That gives me the same error